# Linux freezes during I/O load

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, cinnamon, freeze

I use Linux Mint with Dell XPS 15 as work laptop and build a large Android application using gradle.

With all optimizations it still uses almost all available RAM (16 GB) and starting to use SWAP from swapfile (maybe, I should use swap partition instead?). It causes a high I/O rate and Cinnamon (and all other applications) have freezes.

Also, I tried to test, that I/O is a reason of these problems and found, that running `dd` command for creating load to my I/O system also cause the same problems. (I couldn't reproduce this behavior on Mac OS, for example)

I found that I should change I/O scheduler type to `deadline`, but my `/sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler` file contains just `none` option. And as I understand right it means that https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Multi-Queue_Block_IO_Queueing_Mechanism_(blk-mq) framework is used and I shouldn't to change anything.

**Question:** How I can solve these freezes during I/O load? Maybe, what metrics should I analyze for getting more information?

Environment:

```
OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
Cinnamon: 3.6.7
Linux Kernel: 4.13.0-38-generic
```

Comment: please show the exact `dd` command you are using to test. Also if you could show the `top` headers (first 5 lines) that would help as well.

Comment: I cannot remember anymore how many exchanges I had with Linus and Alan on this. Over the past 15+ years I have been going back and forth in many bugzillas trying to hammer home the idea that scheduler freezing the OS when someone copies a large file is a bad, bad implementation. These bug reports have for the most part been closed due to "end of life" and never looked into. Linux freezing during prolonged IO operations is a black eye for both Torvalds and Cox for the last couple decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With all optimizations it still uses almost all available RAM (16 GB)

*it* — who? Typically every general purpose OS designed since 1970s uses all available RAM or its huge part for slow storage content caching intensively. If *it* means **VM cache** what troubles are there? Run `free -m` and study its output, it used to have special indication of "+/- cache/buffers" hinting that it's not irrevocable used — *cache would shrink if there's memory pressure*.

It's pretty typical misconception a novice would have…

---

> I found that I should change I/O scheduler type to deadline

Schedulers are there for slow devices like HDDs. With SSDs/NVME it's just extra overhead — you don't need to have queue for requests because there's no gain in re-ordering them — contrary to HDDs where it plays significant role reducing seek times.

---

> How I can solve these freezes during I/O load?

There're no mindreaders here (*being an exception I prefer to keep my talent hidden so others saved from envy*), `dd` can be run in different ways, why didn't you just add a snippet showing how exactly it was run?

P. S. Generally I can advice updating kernel, because it could be specific driver quirks that got (or didn't) resolved.